# Translate error message no result from catalog search

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

i was looking to find where is writed this message:

> "Maximum words count is 8. In your search query was cut next part:
>   test9."

I search it, and found is here:

```
<p class="note-msg">
    <?php echo ($this->getNoResultText()) ? $this->getNoResultText() : $this->__('Your search returns no results.') ?>
    <?php if ($messages = $this->getNoteMessages()):?>
        <?php foreach ($messages as $message):?>
        <br /><?php echo $message?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</p>
```

But don't know how could translate this message.

I already try to translate on Mage_CatalogSearch.csv in the appropiate language.

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the translate override to your theme.

If you add a translate.csv file in the following

app/design/frontend/yourtheme/yourpackage/locale/en_GB/translate.csv

change en_GB to what ever your site language is.

You can then add the string you want to translate to the translate.csv file

add the string to the first column

Maximum words count is %1$s. In your search query was cut next part: %2$s.

and add the translation to the column to the right

MY translation %1$s. In your search query was cut next part my translation: %2$s.

Dont forget to clear all caches after you have done this

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was offuscated to make a translation by "Mage::helper" and trying to found where this message was created, but this is a great solution!